# Command-line tool to split video at timepoints?

Tags: macos, video, editing, video-editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Script for cutting videos based on edit list](https://superuser.com/questions/419398/script-for-cutting-videos-based-on-edit-list)

I have an hour-long video that I want to split into individual clips at arbitrary timepoints. I could do this by hand in iMovie, or even borrow a machine with Final Cut, but there are upwards of thirty separate clips, so doing it manually strikes me as time-consuming and error-prone.

(It's a sequence of recordings for a language textbook, but it's all one file, and it's unwieldy not to be able to separately view, repeat, etc. the chapter-by-chapter clips. Currently it's an H.264 MPEG-4 but I'm not adverse to converting it.)

I know all the timepoints, and I'd like to feed a list of them to something, or build a script around the list, to produce the split clips without further human intervention. Linux would be okay but Mac OS would be ideal; Windows isn't really an option.

Suggestions?

Comment: See the script I posted there. It's not 100% perfect, but should get you started.

Comment: Ping me if you have troubles getting it to work. I've only used it for video, so the audio support is rather limited. You might not always want to do a bitstream copy but re-encode the video while cutting too. Don't forget to install the latest FFmpeg though. Older versions might choke on some options there.